# Spring Config Server: pick git credentials from Vault

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I'm able to set up a git repository a config backend:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
#          username: user
#          password: '{cipher}passwd'
```

I think it's not a good practive to provide user and password straightforwardly herewith on `bootstrap.yml` file.

I'd like they are picked up from Vault.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring cloud vault to do so, Spring offers a start guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/vault-config/)

Comment: Is it possible to use Vault config client inside a config server? Isn't going to run into a timeout on startup? I don't know if I've explained so well.